# What types of species can produce genetically identical offspring?

Tags: genetics, reproduction, pregnancy

Talking about identical twins, triplets, etc.  I'm curious which types of species are able produce genetically identical offspring.  Let's limit the scope to species that reproduce sexually and instances where the offspring differ genetically from the parents but are identical to that of at least one of their siblings. Are there phyla, classes, et cetera that do not ever produce identical twins?  Kingdoms?  Are there cases of plants producing genetically identical offspring?

Comment: you ought to clarify as well whether or not you mean fraternal versus identical twins (or higher level pregnancies) - - - many animals (e.g. cats, dogs, rodents) have "litters" of offspring, but whether or not any of those might represent 'twins' is probably difficult to tell (or not easily detectable)

Comment: Are you looking for a list of all known species that have been documented to produce twins etc? If so that is too broad a question. If not, it remains unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @James It sounds like they're asking which taxonomic groups are capable of genetically-identical multiple births, rather than a list of species. Which sounds to me like it could be an interesting question, except that I strongly suspect there will be some species in almost any higher level group for which they haven't been documented, so I'm not sure it's answerable in its current form. Maybe it could be edited to "what biological processes facilitate or prevent viable genetically-identical multiple births" or something - OP, would you be happy with that?

Comment: @arboviral That would be a more satisfying question.